# Elasticsearch connect range and term to same array item

Tags: elasticsearch, elastica, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a user document with a field called **experiences** which is an array of objects, like:

```
{
  "experiences": [
    {
      "end_date": "2017-03-02",
      "is_valid": false
    },
    {
      "end_date": "2015-03-02",
      "is_valid": true
    }
  ]
}
```

With this document I have to search users where end date is in last year and is_valid is true.
At this time I have a **query -> bool** and I add two must there, one **range** for the *end_date* and one **term** for the *is_valid*.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": {
        "term": {
          "experiences.is_valid": true
        },
        "range": {
          "experiences.end_date": {
            "gte": "now-1y",
            "lte": "now"
          }
        },
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result is that this user is selected because he has an **end_date** in the last year (the first exp.) and another exp. with **is_valid true**.
Of course this is not what I need, because I need that **end_date** and **is_valid** must be referenced to the same object, but how can we do this on Elasticsearch?

**Mapping**:

```
"experiences": {
  "properties": {
    "comment": {
      "type": "text",
      "fields": {
        "keyword": {
          "type": "keyword",
          "ignore_above": 256
        }
      }
    },
    "end_date": {
      "type": "date"
    },
    "id": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "is_valid": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "start_date": {
      "type": "date"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Share mapping of your index.. `GET index/type/_mapping`. I guess experience is of type `object`.

Comment: Added, but there's no "type" for experiences...

Comment: Default is "Object" .. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change `experiences` type to [Nested data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html).

Then apply `nested` query :

```
 {
 "query": {
  "nested": {
     "path": "experiences",
     "query": {
        "bool": {
           "must": [
              {
                 "term": {
                    "experiences.is_valid": true
                 }
              },
              {
                 "range": {
                    "experiences.end_date": {
                       "gte": "now-1y",
                       "lte": "now"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        }
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

This is due to the way arrays of objects are flattened in Elasticsearch.
Study more [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#_how_arrays_of_objects_are_flattened)

Comment: Thank you, I'll try in the next days!