# elasticsearch range and term filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to create a filtered index alias in Elastic 2.X

The following gives me all teenagers regardless of gender.  I only want to see the females in this filter.

This is what I am trying to create the index alias:

```
"add" : {
        "index" : "myindex",
        "alias" : "teenage_female",
        "filter" : 
        {
            "bool" : 
            {
                "must" : 
                [               
                    { "term": { "gender": "female" } },
                    { "range": { "age": { "gt": "12", "lt": "20" } } }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have looked at this question which seems to be the same answer however there must be something wrong in my JSON.

[Elasticsearch connect range and term to same array item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44266252/elasticsearch-connect-range-and-term-to-same-array-item)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filter can not be an array unless it is wrapped in a "bool" with "must".

The following filter works correctly:

```
  "filter" : 
  {
    "bool" : 
    {
      "must" : 
      [
        { "term": { "gender": "female" } },
        { "range": { "age": { "gt": "12", "lt": "20" } } }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here a little bit, but according to the [Filtered Index Aliases](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/indices-aliases.html#filtered) docs, the add alias request works with [filter context](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.2/query-filter-context.html) (as opposed to query context)

Try this:

```
"add" : {
    "index" : "myindex",
    "alias" : "teenage_female",
    "filter" : [               
         { "term": { "gender": "female" } },
         { "range": { "age": { "gt": "12", "lt": "20" } } }
     ]
}
```

Comment: I understand why this should work but it does not.  When I retrieve the index aliases after adding this it only has the second range value as the filter not the gender term.  I have deleted and recreated and it's the same result.  The first part of the filter is ignored in the creation of the alias.